# What changes contentOffset when a UIScrollView with contentInset changes its frame from an autoresize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have an issue where a scroll view will behave as expected on an iPhone 5 screen (320 points wide) but will have a negative horizontal `contentOffset` when it's autoresized by its super view to fit an iPhone 6 screen (375 points wide). The reason the offset can be negative is because the view also has a `contentInset` to the left. But since it was 0 before the automatic resize, I would expect it to still be 0 after.

I am setting up a `UIScrollView` inside the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method of a `UITableViewCell` subclass like this:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0);
[self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
```

I can confirm that the `contentOffset` is (0, 0) at this point (presumably because everything gets autoresized to fit the iPhone 6 screen at a later point in time). I tried probing the value in various methods. In `setFrame` it's (0, 0) but in the first call to `layoutSubviews` it's (-55, 0) – presumably because the difference between iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 horizontal display points is 375 - 320 = 55.

Here's a screenshot of what happens on an iPhone 6 screen (in this screenshot I have put additional views inside the scroll view so that it can be seen graphically):
[image]

Comment: The line `scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size` is a red flag because it's not consistent with the use of the autoresizingMask.  What is the contentView's width at this point?  I'm guessing it's 320 pts.  If the contentView size changes at a later time then the autoresizingMask will take care of the scrollView's frame, but it won't take care of the scrollView's content size.

Comment: Yep that's one problem. I've tried keeping the `contentSize` updated in multiple places. If I do it in `setFrame`, it works fairly well if I use the new `frame` value, but it breaks down because that value doesn't take into consideration things that affect the scroll view such as borders etc. And I can't use the adjusted value of `self.contentView.bounds` because it hasn't been updated yet in `setFrame`.